# View Swiss Play Store from within the EU

Tags: google-play

we have developed an app and now released it in multiple countries. While I can see the options under in den [developer account](https://play.google.com/console/) I would like to double check in the [stores](https://play.google.com/). This is easy for counties with in the EU and EWR as described [hear](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid).
But is it possible for countries outside like Switzerland? Again I do not want to buy or install any app from there, I basically just want to check if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. Just add "&gl=CH" to the url of the play store